# How can I avoid that a Spring controller method return a logical view name and return a String value used to handle and AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and AJAX and I have the following doubt.

Using jQuery I am performing this AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "salvaAppuntiMinisteriale",

    data: { 
        'codiceProgetto': codiceProgetto,
        'appuntiMinisteriale': appuntiMinisteriale
          }

    }).done(function(response) {
        showSuccessMessage('Nota inserita');
        document.open();
        document.write(response);
        document.close();

    }).error(function(xhr) {
        manageError(xhr);
});
```

As you can see, perform a request toward the **salvaAppuntiMinisteriale** resource passing to it two values (that are retrieved from my page, it works fine).

Then, into a Spring MVC controller class, I have this controller method that handle the previous AJAX request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "salvaAppuntiMinisteriale", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String salvaAppuntiMinisteriale(@RequestParam String codiceProgetto, @RequestParam String appuntiMinisteriale, Model model) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("CODICE PROGETTO: " + codiceProgetto + " NOTA MINISTERIALE: " + appuntiMinisteriale);

    Twp1007Progetto progetto = progettoService.getProgetto(Integer.parseInt(codiceProgetto));

    progetto.setDesNotApp(appuntiMinisteriale);

    progetto.setCodPgmUltMov("Inserimento nota minitseriale");              // Codice azione ultima modifica
    progetto.setCodUteUltMov(this.getUtenteConnesso().getUsername());       // Utente ministeriale che ha variato l'anticipo
    progetto.setDatOraUltMov(new Date());                                   // Data ed ora della variazione dell'anticipo

    progettoService.salvaNotaAppunto(progetto);

    model.addAttribute("progetto", progetto);

    return "visualizzaProspetto/prospettoRendicontazione";
}
```

This works fine. It correctly handle the previous request and return the logical name of an entire view that will be entirely reloaded in the current tab by these lines into my previous jQuery code:

```
document.open();
document.write(response);
document.close();
```

This works fine but not I want change this behavior and I want avoid that the entire page is returned and reloaded.

So what I need to do are the following operations:

1. I don't want that the previous **salvaAppuntiMinisteriale()** controller method return a logical view name (because I have not to reload a page).
2. The **salvaAppuntiMinisteriale() method have to return the value of the **appuntiMinisteriale** from my **progetto** object (I have to retrieve it to be sure that the value is correctly saved in the DB, but this is not important now). Maybe have I to put it into the **ResponseBody**?
3. Into the callback function called into the **done()** of my jQuery done I have to retrieve the previous value so I can update the content of an HTML field into my page.

So, how can I implement this behavior? How can I avoid to return the logical view name and return a String value and then retrieve it into the **.done()** function?

Comment: Annotate the method with `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: It's not _entirely_ clear how you're planning to wire this all together, but try annotating your controller method with `@ResponseBody` (though usually returning a JSON object is preferable to a bare string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the object you want to pass to front-end and annotate your controller with `@RestController` annotation, or controller method with `@ResponseBody`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to parse `json`, so it is better you use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`, this tells Spring you are doing RESTful service calls.

Your controller, I'd rewrite like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "salvaAppuntiMinisteriale", method=RequestMethod.GET,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity< Twp1007Progetto > salvaAppuntiMinisteriale(@RequestBody Twp1007Progetto progetto ) throws Exception {
 //your logic here
 return new ResponseEntity<>(progetto, HttpStatus.OK));
}
```